# system.rank, system.keywords from SystemIndex

Tags: windows, vb.net, datareader

Looking to fetch some nice results working with Microsoft Search.

Got some problems...

First system.rank returns allways 1000.
I tried system.HitCount, it returns allways 65535.

Then I'm trying to match a word in the Keywords using System.Keywords...

The results of the request looks allways empty on Keywords?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks

Comment: Well I'm working with Microsoft Search, all is allright except the results for the field System.Keywords is empty. So without tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
strQuery = "SELECT SYSTEM.FILENAME, System.Keywords FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE scope= '" & scope & "' AND SYSTEM.FILENAME NOT LIKE '%.tmp' AND SYSTEM.FILENAME NOT LIKE '~$%' "

Dim constring As String = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';"
Using con As New OleDbConnection(constring)

    con.Open()

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, con)
    Dim table AS new DataTable()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim dc AS New DataColumn()
    Dim cmdSearch As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strQuery, con)
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmdSearch.ExecuteReader()
    Dim result As New ArrayList()

    table.Columns.Add("filename")
    table.Columns.Add("DocKeywords")

    If reader.HasRows Then

        Do While reader.Read()

            Dim row As Datarow = table.NewRow()

            row("filename") = reader.Item("system.filename") 
            row("DocKeywords") = reader.Item("System.Keywords") 'String.Join(",", reader.Item("System.Keywords"))  'system.string[]: empty

            table.Rows.Add(row)

        Loop

    End If

    DataGrid1.DataSource = table
    DataGrid1.DataBind()
```